# Regex to match required/optional elements and nothing else

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match two items in any order, but also allow two other optional elements. The regex should only match these two to four items, and nothing else.

For example, I want to match "high" and "unrounded" with optional "back" and "tense".

Input:

```
high back tense unrounded     # ==> match (two required elements + two optional)
high unrounded                # ==> match (just two required, no optional elements)
unrounded high                # ==> match (two required elements, any order)
high back unrounded           # ==> match (two required elements and one optional one)
tense unrounded back high     # ==> match (any order + optional elements)
lax unrounded                 # ==> no match (doesn't include one required element)
high back tense unrounded lax # ==> no match (includes more than the two required and two optional elements)
```

Her's my current Regex:

```
(?i)(?=.*high)((?=.*back))?((?=.*tense))?(?=.*unrounded)
```

It matches everything that I want but also matches things like the last example - which I don't want. Can I get it to NOT match with something that contains more than these two required elements and two optional elements?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Are you using a programming language? Also, can your string contain more than one of any of the elements?

Comment: I think a full regex solution to this would involve verbose alternation regardless - which indicates that it's a problem better solved using other tools, at least at first

Comment: Which programming language are you using? This can be much more easily and readably done with a programming language since regex is not suited to word exclusions.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what programing language is used, because this is for a quiz I have created on eLC (eLearning Commons). Perhaps a better way is to allow two answers: one with the required elements and one with the optional elements. ... In fact, I'm not sure why I didn't think of that to begin with. I suppose I just wanted to solve it with a regex.
@AhmedAbdelhameed, no, it shouldn't contain more than one of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you insist on using regex, you can try something like this:

```
^(?=.*high)(?=.*unrounded)(?:(?:high|back|tense|unrounded)(?: |$))+$
```

[**Try it online**](https://regex101.com/r/h99g75/1).

**Details:**

- `^(?=.*high)(?=.*unrounded)` Makes sure the string contains both "high" and "unrounded".
- `(?:` Start of the outer non-capturing group.

  - `(?:high|back|tense|unrounded)` A non-capturing group - matches any of these 4 words.
  - `(?: |$)` Matches a space character or asserts position at the end of the line.
- `)+` End of the outer non-capturing group and matches one or more instances of it.
- `$` Asserts position at the end of the line.

---

Note: If you need to make sure none of the words is repeated in the string, you can add a negative lookahead after each one of them. For example:

```
^(?=.*high)(?=.*unrounded)(?:(?:high(?!.*high)|back(?!.*back)|tense(?!.*tense)|unrounded(?!.*unrounded))(?: |$))+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h99g75/2)**.